# Passing parameters to JQuery on() to get Array parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

i have an array,

```
[0][video object]
[0][state]
[0][parameters]

[1][video object]
[1][state]
[1][parameters]
.
.
.
```

i want to know where all videos in array can be played:

```
for(i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
    $(videos[i]['video']).on('canplaythrough', function(){

       //do stuff - check all
       update parent > ['state'] to true;

    }
}
```

The problem is after i loose the index i. How can i pass it inside on() function?
i want to get the parent of the array item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loosing the value of `i` because it is a closure variable, in the given case since you are iterating through an array I think it is better to use $.each() here

```
$.each(videos, function(idx, video){
    $(video.video).on('canplaythrough', function(){

       //do stuff - check all
       video.state = true

    }
})
```

Comment: impressive clean solution

Answer (score 1):

to use the `var i` inside your `on` function you can do the following

```
for(i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
    $(videos[i]['video']).on('canplaythrough', function(i){
       console.log(i); // i is accessible here now
       //do stuff - check all
       videos[i]['state'] = true;

    }
}
```